# Printing tid value on OPENMP turns error omp_get_num_thread()

Tags: fortran, openmp

I want to parallelize the following code, and find which thread doing which task

```
subroutine costfunction(r,n,k,distancereg,indices,new_centro,cluster,cost,tid)
203     integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out)  :: distancereg, indices
204     integer, dimension (:), allocatable, intent(out) :: cluster
205     real, dimension (:,:), allocatable, intent(in) :: r
206     real, dimension (:,:), intent(in), allocatable :: new_centro
207     real, dimension(:), intent(out), allocatable :: cost
208     integer :: i,k
209     integer, intent (in):: tid
210     allocate(cluster(k))
211     allocate(cost(k))
212     allocate(distancereg(k))
213 
214     call min_distance(r,n,k,centroid,distance,indices,distancereg)
215     cluster = 0
216    
217    !$OMP PARALLEL DO private  (i,k)  shared (cluster,cost,indices)
218     tid = omp_get_thread_num()
219      do i=1,k
220        cost(i)=0
221        cluster(i)=count(indices==i)
222        cost(i)=(1.0/cluster(i))*distancereg(i)
223      print*, tid
224     end do
225    !$OMP END PARALLEL DO
226     print*," total sum of cluster members ",sum(cluster)," vs N ",n
227     
228  end subroutine
```

But when it turns error on line 218 (tid) saying that unexpected assignment statement.
I dont know where is the mistake,

Comment: At line 209 the code declares that `tid` is an `intent(in)` argument to the subroutine.  That's kind of like a promise not to set its value inside the routine, then bang, at line 218 you try to break that promise ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!$omp parallel do` should include only a do loop, no other statements.

If you want other statements, you can use an ordinary `!$omp parallel` region with an `!$omp do` inside. It is not required to combine the `parallel` and `do` into a single directive even if there is just the loop and nothing more.